# JAVA - Switch case never triggers a value

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, case, runnable

I haven't found a similar problem prior to posting.

I have a simple Java `Runnable` that gets an `int variable`, outputs the value to a dialog, then decreases this variable by 1 and does a `postDelayed` of 1000ms, before showing the next value.

When the counter is `1`, the `Runnable` shows "GO!" on that dialog.

When the counter is `0`, the `Runnable` must to dismiss the dialog, and stop itself, by using `removeCallbacksAndMessages(null)`.

This is the Runnable:

```
private Runnable runnableCountdown = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        TextView tv_countdown = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_countdown);

        switch(count) {
            case 0:
                startChron();
                stopCountdown();
                break;
            case 1:
                tv_countdown.setText("GO!");
                break;
            default:
                tv_countdown.setText(String.valueOf(count - 1));
                countdown.postDelayed(this, 1000);
                break;
        }

        count--;
    }
};
```

The problem is in the `switch ... case`: It never executes the case for when the variable's value is `0`.

Because they never enter on case `0`, the dialog is never closed and the next `Runnable` is never started.

What am I missing on my switch case?

Comment: that's not enough, show entire class.

Comment: what's inside `startChron()` and `stopCountdown()`?

Comment: how do you know it never enters 0?

Comment: need more code .. what is initial count value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call runnableCountdown.postDelayed(this, 1000); after you decrement the count

```
private Runnable runnableCountdown = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    TextView tv_countdown = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv_countdown);

    switch(count) {
        case 0:
            startChron();
            stopCountdown();
            break;
        case 1:
            tv_countdown.setText("GO!");
            break;
        default:
            tv_countdown.setText(String.valueOf(count - 1));

            break;
    }

    count--;
    runnableCountdown.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}
};
```

Comment: You are most welcome.Please accept my answer as the right answer.